# Spotify App List of Playlists

Tags: javascript, spotify

I am trying to display a list of the current users playlists in the native spotify List.

I've got this to get the users playlist:

```
require([
  '$api/models',
  '$views/list#List',
  '$api/library#Library'
], function(models, List, Library) {
  'use strict';

  var UsersLibrary = Library.forCurrentUser();


  var test = function() 
  {
    console.log(UsersLibrary.playlists);
    var playlists = UsersLibrary.playlists.snapshot().done(function(s){

      var length = s.length;

      for(var x = 0; x < length; x++)
      {
        var meta = s._meta[x];
        if(!meta.name) continue ; // skip folders
      }

    });    
  };

  exports.test = test;
});
```

And i can loop over the playlists no problem. The problem starts when i try to use the spotify List object and create a list. I tried this (and a few variations with the same result):

```
var test = function() 
  {
    console.log(UsersLibrary.playlists);
    var playlists = UsersLibrary.playlists.snapshot().done(function(s){

      var list = List.forCollection(s._collection, {"layout":'table'});
    });    
  };
```

As soon as I call .forCollection I get  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of null`.

After debugging for awhile I found the problem comes when one of the spotify API scripts tries to access the `uri` field on the collection which is undefined.

Is there some other way to go about this or something im missing? I was thinking there would be a uri for the users playlists but i couldn't find anything.

Thanks,

-Ken

Answer (score 2):

The collection contains a set of playlists. You can load all of them calling its `loadAll` function:

```
require([
  '$api/models',
  '$views/list#List',
  '$api/library#Library'
], function(models, List, Library) {
  'use strict';

  var UsersLibrary = Library.forCurrentUser();

  var test = function() {
    UsersLibrary.playlists.snapshot().done(function(s){
      s.loadAll().done(function(playlists){
        // playlists is an array of Playlist objects
      });
    });
  };

  exports.test = test;
});
```

If you would like to create a `List` for a specific playlist, you would do:

```
var playlist = playlist[0]; // we pick, for example, the first one
playlists.load('tracks').done(function(p) {
  var list = List.forCollection(p.tracks, {"layout":'table'});
  document.body.appendChild(list.node);
  list.init();
});
```

Comment: I actually want the list to contain the names of the playlists not all of the tracks, ill try the loadAll thing and see if that gets me any closer

Comment: Then, try loading the 'name' property instead of 'tracks'.

Comment: Is this covered by the documentation somehow? Do you have any pointers?

Comment: All the information is on the [API documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/index.html). You will probably want to have a look at [Collection](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-collection.html) and [Library](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-library-library.html).